# C++ Json Config Read And Write

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to make a basic json config system. But for some Reason in my Read and Write Functions I get this weird error I dont understand why it happens

```
#define READ(j, var) v::var = j[#var];
#define READ_ARR(j, var) std::copy(j[#var].begin(), j[#var].end(), v::space::var);
#define WRITE(j, var) j[#var] = v::var;

void Config::Load() {

    if (GetSelectedName() == NULL)
        return;
    nlohmann::json j;
    std::fstream read(configDir + std::string("/") + GetSelectedName());
    read >> j;
    read.close();

    READ(j, aimbot.toggle); // error code E0276 A name followed by "::" must be a class or 
    namespace name.    

}

void Config::Save() {
    if (GetSelectedName() == NULL)
        return;
    nlohmann::json j;

    WRITE(j, aimbot.toggle); // error code E0276 A name followed by "::" must be a class or 
    namespace name.    

    std::ofstream write(configDir + std::string("/") + GetSelectedName());
    write << j << std::endl;
    write.close();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get? on which line?

Comment: In `#define READ(j, var) v::var = j[#var];`, what is `v`? No such identifier is declared in the code shown. E.g. `READ(j, aimbot.toggle)` would expand to `v::aimbot.toggle = j["aimbot.toggle"]`. Apparently, there's no namespace or class named `v`, rendering this expansion meaningless.

Comment: Please show a [mre]